# Blockchain port error-Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I locally deployed my nodejs app, I encountered the following port error.

```
ERROR    GET blockchain/blocks    OUTPUT: ****{"code":"EAI_AGAIN","errno":"EAI_AGAIN","syscall":"getaddrinfo","hostname":"vp0","host":"vp0","port":"7050"}
```

UNABLE TO WRITE LOGS TO FILE****

Comment: What command did you run?

Comment: the command  i gave is node app.js, and opened the console and viewed the home page on localhost 8080, when tried to access the other pages, i encountered the above error.